# delete a rows using checkbox in datagridview

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I has one problem in i know how to delete single row with the help of header selction of a gatagridview. i want your help in which how can i delete a multiple rows using checkbox.....
But i preserved a row sequence... how i can delete a row using checkbox in datagridview with a click of button......give me any reference for it ...
site...or code.....

Answer (score 1):

My Cell for the check box is called: ToDelete

Code in form for button:

```
Private Sub Button_Delete_Checked_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button_Delete_Checked.Click
    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
        If row.Cells("ToDelete").Value Then
            MessageBox.Show(row.Cells("SomeText").Value & " will be deleted.")

        End If

    Next
End Sub
```

[image]

Here's the grid to give you an idea of the fields and data I manually entered.

[image]
Result of clicking the button.

You'll need to insert code to do the deletion in place of the messagebox code. You can get the row index with: row.Index.